# how to test a unit test using pytest django if there is a function defined but not the class?

Tags: django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_search(request):
    search_text = get_searchText()
    return Reponse({"search-txt":search_text})
```

here, search_txt is an api for searching the text,and search_text is a variable

I tried below but was unable to test the above code,

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class TestViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.client = Client()
       self.searchtxt_url = reverse('search-txt')
   
    def test_search_project(self):
       response.self.client.get(self.searchtxt_url)
       self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

what can be a possible way to test a function with api

Comment: 1. `search_txt is an api` there is no such thing as `search_txt` in the code you pasted. 2. What is `response` in `response.self.client.get(self.searchtxt_url)`? It wasn't defined anywhere in the code you pasted. 3. What you wanted to test is unclear. Do you want to test the API `get_search`? Or the API `get_searchText`?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing what you wanted to write was

```
def test_search_project(self):
    response = self.client.get(self.searchtxt_url)
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

You have to store the response of your `self.searchtxt_url` in the `response` object and then you can assert its fields/values.

Comment: No this will not help, I already tried that thing. what I want to do is a unit test the search function using pytest django where I've used search api.